# ruamel.yaml CommentedMap is not compatible with dict in update() (has a bug?)

Tags: yaml, ruamel.yaml

The code below reproduces the issue:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

ordered_dict = OrderedDict(a = 1, b = 2)
replacement = dict(a = 3, b = 4)
ordered_dict.update(**replacement)
print(ordered_dict)  # this is to show that OrderedDict is compatible with dict

commented_map = YAML().load('''\
a: 1
b: 2
''')

commented_map.update(**replacement)  # should work like dict's update()
print(commented_map)
```

**Output**

The first part

```
OrderedDict([('a', 3), ('b', 4)])
```

shows that `OrderedDict` is compatible with `dict`

However the `commented_map` part raises an exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ruamel_bug.py", line 14, in <module>
    commented_map.update(**replacement)
  File "D:\venv\Ruamel\lib\site-packages\ruamel\yaml\comments.py", line 881, in update
    self._ok.add(*kw.keys())
TypeError: set.add() takes exactly one argument (2 given)
```

My current work-around is to edit the source code to modify line 881 into

```
for key in kw.keys(): self._ok.add(key)
```

then everything became OK!!!  Therefore I believe it is a bug in line 881.

I was going to create a ticket for the project, but the instruction asked me to post here first, to clarify that it is not a faulty usage of the library.

Is it a bug? Or my misusage?

Thank you in advance.

Environment: ruamel.yaml==0.17.21 with Python 3.11 on 64 bit Windows

Comment: This should now be fixed in 0.17.23

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the intention is that `CommentedMap` behaves like a `dict`, and this has been implemeted for `dict`'s so long ago, this should probably be called a bug instead of a missing feature. I added a ticket on sourceforge for this.

In `ruamel.ordereddict`, the implementation of the original C mapping that kept insertion order (on which `CommentedMap` for Python 2 relies heavily), the `.update()` doesn't take keywords either. That package was developed back in 2007, still three years after Python 2.4 was released, so that is IMO somewhat more understandable it is not in there. So maybe that is why this is not (fully) implemented in `ruamel.yaml`

Until that has been fixed (done in 0.17.23), you can do `update(replacement)` (i.e. pass in the dict as parameter) instead of expanding them to key-value parameters with `update(**replacement)`

Comment: According to your "missing feature" answer and the ticket name [`update should take keywords`](https://sourceforge.net/p/ruamel-yaml/tickets/455/), now I see presently the correct usage should be
`commented_map.update(replacement)` instead of `commented_map.update(**replacement)`.  OK, it really works.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I update the answer to make that "workaround" more apparent, so that people don't need to read the comments. Sorry for not making that more clear in the first place.

Comment: I also removed my **EDIT** part.  Therefore my question is pure question and the solution is in your answer.